# Are my answers right here about true and false statements?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

1. Every integer is a rational number -> false -- correct?
2. Let r = true; s = true. Is this statement true or false? $$\lnot [r \lor (\lnot s \lor r)];\quad$$  -> true -- correct?
3. Let p = true; r = false; q = false. Is the following statement true or false?
   $$\lnot [\lnot q \lor(p \lor \lnot r)$$  -> false -- correct?

Comment: For #1, you _are_ permitted to express an integer $ \ n \ $ as $ \ \frac{n}{1} \ . $

Comment: Every integer *is* a rational number.

Comment: @Ittay Weiss: that issue is one of the well known intractable problems. on this site. In elementary math people learn that $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ but in the usual presentations that construct each of these from the previous one (e.g. in abstract algebra), those subset relations are all literally false, e.g. an integer is an equivalence class of pairs of natural numbers, and so a natural number is not an integer according to those definitions. It's completely a matter of viewpoint.

Comment: @CarlMummert I assumed OP was talking about number systems here. Which set theoretic constructions is used to produce the next number system from the previous one in the tower you mention is irrelevant. All that matters is the axioms that the system satisfy and of course that the rationals contain an isomorphic copy of the integers, and then immediately the integers are identified with certain rationals. I don't anybody actually thinks of rationals as equivalence classes of pairs of integers, nor of the reals as Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences....

Comment: @IttayWeiss There have existed some logicians who at least seem to have thought that an isomorphism (in the sense of category theory) isn't enough... at least from their language.  At least from what I can tell, certain logicians of the Warsaw-Lvov school wouldn't even call this "c" here and this "c" here the same, I guess since they occupied differently places (perhaps also because if you look at them with a powerful enough microscope, you might start to see differences).  They would just call the first "c" and the second "c" equiform.  That may seem hairsplitting, but...

Comment: You might want to think about the difference between the notion of equality as it gets used in mathematics, and logical equivalence.  That certain operations associate may sometimes seem intuitive and obvious (at least to some people), but that two-valued logical equivalence associates many people don't find intuitive.  Or so it seems from a recent question on here.  And we do know that Polish logicians of the Lvov-Warsaw school fared much better at the two-valued equivalential calculus than many other schools of logic.  So, maybe there does exist something to such a distinction here.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I'm unfamiliar with the Lvov-Warsaw school of logic. I find such distinctions strange. A number is an element in a number system (just like a vector is an element in a vector space). It does not matter what it is, only what you can do with it. Any number system of, say, the reals contains in it a unique number system of rationals. Any number system of the rationals contains in it a unique number system of the integers. The fact that different models exist is irrelevant. It's like saying, given two different models of the reals, is $\sqrt2$ in one equal to $\sqrt2$ in the other.

Comment: The formal answer would be 'it really depends on the models and requires further investigation' but a better answer would be 'who cares?'.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Do you care about the independence of axioms?  I'll remind you that establishing different models of a system oftentimes comes as an excellent way of establishing independence of axioms and tells you information about how a system does behave.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I don't see the relation to independence of axioms here. We are talking about different models for categorical theories (second order of course). All models are isomorphic.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Let's back up, and assume only set theoretic axioms at play (nothing like the identity of zero for addition in the integers).  From what you've told me it would seem that the following reasoning works out as valid.  The (set of all) reals contain an isomorphic copy C of the rationals, this copy C comes as isomorphic to the rationals.  So, you can obtain that copy C from the rationals.  But, that will totally mislead lead you as to the nature of the reals, since we can write a monomorphism, but *not* an epimorphism, from the rationals to the reals.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood this discussion is getting too long for this thread. I suggest we take it to chat or formulate a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't strike out, but only one of your answers is correct:

1. Note that any integer $n$ can be expressed as the fraction: $\dfrac n1$. (In all fairness, the answer depends on how the rational numbers are defined. If we define the integers as a proper subset of the rationals, as suggested by my *note*, then your answer should be *true*.)
2. This is in fact false. $$\lnot[T \lor (F \lor T)] \equiv \lnot [T \lor T] \equiv \lnot [T] = F$$
3. Correct: "false" is the correct answer. $$\lnot [\lnot q \lor(p \lor \lnot r)] \equiv \lnot[\lnot F \lor T \lor\lnot F]  \equiv \lnot[T] \equiv F$$

Comment: Because the question was edited I was able to correct my vote. Thanks,

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes, I edited in part due to a previous comment you left me (different post), about the integers in relation to the rationals. I wanted to be sure here not to be too emphatic about $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$ ;-)